# Timestamp in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, function, datetime

I am trying to measure the time required to execute several functions in javascript. Inside each function I am doing:

```
    function(xyz){
    var startTime = new Date()
    // my function's code goes here
    //
    //end of xyz function's code
    var endTime = new Date()
    console.log("Time of execution of xyz function is: " +(startTime-endTime) + "ms")
    }
```

Unfortuntaely, I am getting the time difference in negative. How is that possible? What time is actually displayed in `new Date()`?

Comment: `startTime-endTime` ... What do you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you are subtracting the larger value from smaller one. You can try one of the following:

```
console.log("Time of execution of xyz function is: " + Math.abs(startTime - endTime) + "ms");
```

or

```
console.log("Time of execution of xyz function is: " +(endTime - startTime) + "ms");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're subtracting a larger value from a smaller value, e.g. `1 - 2 = -1`, hence just swap your variables around:

```
endTime - startTime
```